# Frame Number Overlay With FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to overlay the frame number to each frame of a video file using ffmpeg for windows.

I succeeded in overlaying a timecode stamp with the `drawtext` filter using this code:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -vcodec r210 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: timecode='01\:00\:00\:00': r=25: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" -y output.mov
```

However, I need a frame number overlay and not a timecode one. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the [drawtext filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) with the `n` or `frame_num` function:

[image]
<sub>Looping 5 fps example</sub>

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy output
```

- You may have to provide the full path to the font file, such as `fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf`.
- `n`/`frame_num` starts at 0, but you can make the frame count start from 1 with the `start_number` option as shown in the example.

You could add additional text if desired, but be aware that you have to escape some special characters:

```
text='Frame\: %{frame_num}'
```

[image]

See the [drawtext filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) for more info.

Comment: It works! Is there any way to make it start the count from 1?

Comment: there may be an "eval" option you can throw in there to add it together...

Comment: on Win: if error >>Could not load font "Arial.ttf"<< occur you can copy the font e.g. "Arial" from the Windows\fonts-folder to the Image-File-Folder

Comment: Add `fontsize=200:` to actually see something ;)

Comment: I meant that one can increase the default font size, if needed.

Comment: I had to explicitly give the entire path of my ttf file which was /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf

Comment: I noticed that this significantly degrades the quality. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @llogan I was using your command exactly as you have it here. I solved quality degradation by adding the `-qscale 1` option to your command. It still degrades the quality noticeably (and reduces file size by ~30%) , but was good enough for my purposes. Thanks!

Comment: @llogan here it is: `ffmpeg -i input -qscale 1 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy output`

Comment: Input videos format is avi and codec is MJPG. Output video format is also avi, bu the codec comes out as FMP4

Comment: what version of ffmpeg is this drawfilter available?  Seem to not be working in the one I have. 2.5.3

Comment: @Zak44 Probably since at least FFmpeg 0.8. [drawtext requires ffmpeg to be built with `--enable-libfreetype`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) so yours is probably missing that. 2.5.3 is ancient so you should update regardless. See [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds for Linux, macOS, and Windows. Most of these should have drawtext included.

Comment: I see... well I tried the latest, and it seems to have just made the entire video black. Really odd.  Something is amiss.

Comment: Actually, I take that back.  It seems to work, but has made the video unplayable in Quicktime.  I can open it in VLC and see the frame counter, but the video is no longer recognized as legit in Quicktime, odd!

Comment: @Zak44 Try appending `format=yuv420p` to the filterchain (join the filters with a comma). But this is just a guess without seeing the command and log.

Comment: you can use black@0.5  for a half transparent box color

Comment: Note that if the video is made from a concatenation of video (tested with mp4), it will restart the counter from zero when the concatenated video change. The only solution I found to this problem was to re-encode the video.

Comment: this code only works in terminal but in IDE (Pycharm) is not executed properly. it treated  frame_num as a variable when we replame frame_num with 0 or 1 it is executed make a video but this video has no watermark of current frame it is only simple video with no watermark.