# how to add time counter of exist video file ?

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming

I have some video that i want to add ( on the video display ) some time counter that will show the time form the start of the clip.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want the player to simply show the frame number for the video, then the solution will depend on the particular player you are using. The players will know the frame count, but they may not expose any mechanism to allow you access it. Assuming, they do then you just need to display it on a text overlay above the video.

If you want to embed the frame number in the video itself, so that it will be show on any player when the resulting video is played back, then you can use ffmpeg drawtext filter (http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) to do this. See here for an example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369938/334402