# FFMPEG scene detection: overlay original frame number

Tags: select, ffmpeg, scene, drawtext

I'm able to extract all frames that are not similar to the previous frame from a video file using `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.003),setpts=N/(30*TB)" frame%d.jpg` ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/984841/ffmpeg-remove-parts-without-motion))

I would like to overlay the frame number onto each selected frame. I tried adding `drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf: text='frame\: %{frame_num}': x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1: fontsize=30` to the filter *after* select and setpts, however %{frame_num} returns `1, 2, 3, ...` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364861/frame-number-overlay-with-ffmpeg))

If I put drawtext *before* select and setpts, I get something like `16, 42, 181, ...` as frame numbers (which is exactly what I want), but since the scene detection runs *after* adding the text overlay, changes in the overlay may be detected as well.

Is it possible to do the scene detection and overlay independently from another? `[in] split [out0][out1]` can be used to apply filters separately, but I don't know how to "combine" the results again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Use split first to create two streams. Run scene detection on one, and draw text on another. Then use overlay to paint the numbered stream on the pruned stream - only the corresponding pruned numbered frames will be emitted.

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "split=2[num][raw];[raw]select=gt(scene\,0.003)[raw];[num]drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf: text='frame\: %{frame_num}': x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1: fontsize=30[num];[raw][num]overlay=shortest=1,setpts=N/(30*TB)" -r 30 frame%d.jpg`

Comment: Thank you, this works almost perfectly. It spits out the exact same frames as my first command, just with the text added. But afterwards it keeps writing copies of the last frame, with the frame number incrementing until the total amount of frames in the original video.mp4 is reached. Like this: ```16, 42, 181, 182, 183, ... , 500```

Is there a way to "abort" at 181, in this case?

Comment: Adjusted overlay filter.

Comment: ffmpeg noob here. What is the setpts=N/(30*TB) for?

Comment: The pruned frames can be far apart in time and will retain their original timestamps, so the outputted video will retain its original duration. The setpts is to retime frames so they are played at 30 fps.